# Reversing finite intersection and arbitrary union operations on a subbasis

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set, and $\mathcal{S}$ a set of subsets of $X$. Let $\tau'(\mathcal{S})$ be the set of finite intersections of $\mathcal{S}$, and $\sigma(\tau'(\mathcal{S}))$ the set of arbitrary unions of $\tau'(\mathcal{S})$. Then $\mathcal{T}=\sigma(\tau'(\mathcal{S}))$ is a topology on $X$. My question is, if we reverse the operations $\tau'$ and $\sigma$, do we still get a topology on $X$ ? That is, if we first form arbitrary unions of $\mathcal{S}$ and then their finite intersections, do we get a topology on $X$ ? (In other words, is $\tau'(\sigma(S))$ a topology on $X$ ?) I think I can show $\tau'(\sigma(S))\subseteq\mathcal{T}$, but is it an equality? My guess is no, but is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in general. Take $\Bbb R$ with subbase $\mathcal{S}$ all sets of the form 
$(x,\rightarrow)=\{y\in \Bbb R: y > x\}$ and $(\leftarrow,x)=\{y \in \Bbb R: y < x\}$. This is the standard subbase for any linearly ordered topological space (LOTS), as $\Bbb R$ is.

$\sigma(\mathcal{S})$ contains just $\mathcal{S} \cup \{\Bbb R\}$, plus "gap sets" like $(\leftarrow, x) \cup (y,\rightarrow)=\Bbb R \setminus [x,y]$ for $x < y$.

The finite intersections of these will not give all open subsets of $\Bbb R$: e.g. the complement of the Cantor middle third set won't be formed with finitely many intersections.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is essentially an elaboration of Henno Brandsma's idea:

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of open rays in $\mathbb{R}$.
Then $\sigma(\mathcal{S})$ consists of $\varnothing$, the elements of $\mathcal{S}$, $X=\mathbb{R}$, and the sets of the form
$$(-\infty,a)\cup(b,\infty),$$
where $a\leq b$. Note that they are precisely the complements of the closed rays, closed intervals, and $\varnothing$.
Hence, $\tau'(\sigma(\mathcal{S}))$ consists of the complements of finite unions of these sets. That is, if $\mathcal{C}$ is the set of all closed rays, closed intervals, and $\varnothing$, then
$$\tau'(\sigma(\mathcal{S}))=\rho(\sigma'(\mathcal{C})),$$
where $\rho$ is the complement operation, and $\sigma'$ is the finite union operation.
Now, it is quite clear that a finite union of the elements of $\mathcal{C}$ cannot produce the closed set
$$\bigcup_{n=-\infty}^\infty\left[n,n+\frac{1}{2}\right]=\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(n+\frac{1}{2},n\right)\right)^c.$$
That is,
$$\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(n+\frac{1}{2},n\right)\right)^c\not\in\sigma'(\mathcal{C}).$$
It follows that
$$\sigma(\tau'(\mathcal{S}))\owns\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(n+\frac{1}{2},n\right)\not\in\rho(\sigma'(\mathcal{C}))=\tau'(\sigma(\mathcal{S})).$$